# Environment variable not working in Cygwin

Tags: shell, variables, cygwin, environment

I have to run some shell scripts in Windows using Cygwin. I am able to achieve that using `%BASH% --login -i "/cygdrive/d/script.sh"`, where `%BASH%` is an environment variable in Windows set to `C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe`.

The above script executes without any problem. But when there are Cygwin environment variables inside the .sh files then it doesn't work.

For example, I have a created a Cygwin environment variable `$EXE_PATH = /cygdrive/d/somepath/dir`. Inside my script the line is

```
$EXE_PATH/some.exe -f /cygdrive/d/password.txt
```

There is error in this line every time I run the script.
Error is something to do with the `some.exe/password.txt` not being found.

If I run the same command from the Cygwin terminal, it works fine. Is there something wrong with `/cygdrive`?

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/sh 
#TESTLEELA=/cygdrive/d 
echo simple shell script 

echo $EXE_PATH 

$EXE_PATH/runube.exe -f $TESTLEELA/password.txt DVRP910 *ALL R0006P XJDE0001 QBATCH B H S //NASRVNY1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I have created a Cygwin environment variable"? How and where did you set that variable?

Comment: I created $EXE_PATH in the cygwin terminal by using following steps.            echo "export EXE_PATH=/cygdrive/d/somepath" >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc

Comment: You do that at the start of your script?

Comment: No, I set environment variable on the cygwin terminal. and as I can see ,it is set correctly . even it is substituted inside the script. so the echo $EXE_PATH gives /cygdrive/d/somepath. Is the problem because of the arguments to the exe. Here is the complete script file.                                                                                                                                                       #!/bin/sh
#TESTLEELA=/cygdrive/d
echo simple shell script
echo $EXE_PATH
$EXE_PATH/runube.exe -f $TESTLEELA/password.txt DVRP910 *ALL R0006P XJDE0001 QBATCH B H S //NASRVNY1

Comment: Can you edit your answer with that script? Comments don't preserve newlines. However, setting an environment variable in `.bashrc` won't automatically have it included when you run a script from anywhere other than an interactive Cygwin Bash session.

Comment: I have edited my answer with the script. I am still stuck with this.. nothing seems to work inside of the script, only if i execute the exe from its location it runs fine. one more thing is it required to use ./ to run the exe? Is this correct ? ./$EXE_PATH/runube.exe -f password.txt DVRP910 *ALL R0006P XJDE0001

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
$EXE_PATH = /cygdrive/d/somepath/dir
```

to

```
EXE_PATH=/cygdrive/d/somepath/dir   (in cygwin shell script)
```

Comment: This is the line inside shell script                               $EXE_PATH/some.exe -f /cygdrive/d/password.txt.                  Should I replace it with /cygdrive/d/somepath/dir/some.exe -f /cygdrive/d/password.txt? I tried that but same error is there. And I want to use the Env variable as it is being used in many places

Comment: In one line: You need `$` at the places where the variable is USED. & it must not be there, when the variable is assigned a value.

Comment: I am not using & anywhere. This is my complete shell script.                                                              #!/bin/sh

echo simple shell script
echo $EXE_PATH
$EXE_PATH/runube.exe -f password.txt DVRP910 *ALL R0006P XJDE0001 QBATCH B H S //NASRVNY12002/NY_HP4250_02